# Add link to post which earned you the Quorum badge

Tags: feature-request, badges, per-site-meta

Some badges, especially most of the ones which awarded for a single post, like Nice Answer, have a link to the post(s) where you earned that badge. For Quorum (one post with score of 2 on a child meta), the link is missing:

[image]

Can it be added, please?

Comment: You don't get the badge for a specific post, when the script runs you might have two posts with a score of 2.

Comment: Sure, but that's true for more badges, e.g. Altruist (you can post two bounties before the script runs) or Teacher. I think it's not implemented here because the post is on another site.

Comment: Yeah, being on the other site crossed my mind as well.